# Trying to grab XML from a SSL web service call using Fiddler?

Tags: .net, web-services, ssl, fiddler

Fiddler seems to be killing a webservice call I'm making via SSL.

When I have fiddler capturing traffic (with Decrypt HTTPS traffic and Ignore cert errors both checked), my Web Service call becomes untrusted (I'm able to view SSL in a browser, but the web service call seems to be 'not ignored').  Essentially, I'm trying to catch the XML going up to the web service via a SSL.

Any thoughts or better ways to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Deserialize the object being uploaded and throw to a log.

```
Serialization.XmlSerializer
```

Answer (score 3):

Fiddler works fine for this scenario, and many people use Fiddler this way every day.

Note that you may need to trust the Fiddler Root certificate if you're using any components (e.g. the .NET SOAP framework or the like) that immediately fail for untrusted certificates.

See http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp for more on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try
http://www.parosproxy.org/index.shtml

Answer (score 0):

I have used [stunnel](http://www.stunnel.org/) to remove (or add) SSL for testing. (on Linux and Windows)

Answer (score 0):

A better tool to debug webservice is through firefox's [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) plugin. If you have the console tab enabled in firebug for your site, you can see what kind of error you are getting while calling the webservice or the data returned.

Comment: I was thinking maybe firebug.. going to give it a whirl.